# c program can `uint8_t` point to an address of size 32 bit

Tags: c, pointers, memory

In the code below `get_pic()` returns a pointer of `uint8_t type`.

Then in `main()`, `get_pic()` is called and its return value is cast to the variable `address` which is an `unsigned int`.

The pointer that `get_pic()` returns is to a global array which turns out to be at address `a8000f80`.

My question is that address `a8000f80` is a 32 bit number. Therefore, how can the pointer returned by `get_pic()` point at this address as it is of type `uint8_t` which is only 8 bits?

```
//Function declaration
uint8_t* get_pic(int *piclen);

main() {

  unsigned int address, value;
  address = (unsigned int) get_pic((int*)& value);
}
```

Comment: Don't confuse the size of a pointer to something with the size of that something. (I'm certain that the address of your home – a few dozen characters, possibly – is much smaller than your home.)

Comment: Note that assuming a pointer-to-anything fits into an `unsigned int` is not a conforming assumption. If you have to store a pointer into an integer, use `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`. And even that is strictly valid only for `void *`...

Comment: addresses don't have to be 32 bits. It can be 8, 16, 20, 24, 48 or 64 bits

Comment: ...though if you have 8-bit pointers, you have only 256 memory locations, and you probably shouldn't be using C. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `uint8_t` cannot point anywhere, because it's not a pointer. But an `uint_8*` (pointer to `uint8_t`) can.

You probably want this:

```
uint8_t* get_pic(int *piclen);

main() {
  uint8_t *address;
  int value;

  address = get_pic(&value);
}
```

`get_pic` returns a `uint8_t *`, that is a *pointer* to `uint8_t`), therefore the type of `address` should `uint8_t *`.

The parameter passed to `getpic` is of type pointer to `int` (`int*`), therefore `value` should be of type `int*` too.

Answer (score 1):

It returns a pointer *to* a value of type `uint8_t`; this says nothing about the *size* of the pointer itself.

Answer (score -1):

The size of the pointer has nothing to do with the size of the object, it points to. So, in fact, for most (aka. almost all) implementations, `sizeof($anything *)` is constant (for any `$anything` not being a function).

So `sizeof(uint8_t _*) == sizeof(uint32_t *) == sizeof(unsigned int *) == sizeof(struct foo *)`.

```
uint8_t * get_pic(int * piclen);
```

This returns a pointer to some data. If that data is `uint32_t`, then it's save to assign it to a `uint32_t *`, no cast needed in C (but compilers may warn):

```
int len;
uint32_t * address = get_pic(&len);
```

and then, you can access it using standard syntax.

Also note Michael Walzs answer, he wrote in parallel to me ;)

Comment: `sizeof` is a compile-time operator, and `$anything` looks... strange... in a C context.

Comment: I know, I still like to write `sizeof(stuff)` instead of `sizeof stuff`.

Comment: More as in, how do you figure a compile-time operator could have a non-constant result?

Comment: That is meta speaking and makes clear, that anything may belong there.

Comment: Where do I state or suggest, `sizeof` may return run time variable results? BTW: It can: `int dynamic[num]; size_t num_dependant = sizeof dynamic;`

Comment: How do you figure `get_pic()` returns a pointer to `uint32_t` data when it is *declared* to return `uint8_t *`? How do you figure it's safe to cast the latter to the former? Sorry, this answer is all over the place...

Comment: What part of "If that data is uint32_t" didn't you understand? uint32_t is defined to be 32 bit unsigned without padding, uint8_t is defined to be 8 bit unsigned without padding, so casting between them is well defined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127204/discussion-between-bodo-thiesen-and-devsolar).